# Getting LoggerFactory error tried so many thing added the maven dependency and all but still facing same issue

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Installed All the related thing required to execute or run the selenium Automation Scripts. Please help me as soon as possible.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at org.asynchttpclient.DefaultAsyncHttpClient.<clinit>(DefaultAsyncHttpClient.java:49)
    at org.asynchttpclient.Dsl.asyncHttpClient(Dsl.java:32)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.createHttpClient(NettyClient.java:94)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.<clinit>(NettyClient.java:47)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient$Factory.createClient(NettyClient.java:135)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:116)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:94)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.<init>(DriverCommandExecutor.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriverCommandExecutor.<init>(ChromiumDriverCommandExecutor.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver$ChromeDriverCommandExecutor.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:111)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.generateExecutor(ChromeDriver.java:101)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:84)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:52)
    at selenium.important.main(important.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 15 more
```

Comment: can you add your pom.xml or version of selenium that you are using

Comment: I am using 4.9.0 selenium version

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.